# Move a file using bat from folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move a file from the folder the batch file is in to a folder on the `C:\` drive, and I just can't figure out how.

I tried using `dir` to get the parent folder, but it registered an error.

What would I use?

```
move dir\test.bat C:\Some folder
```

Comment: What error? might help. And if you put path with spaces in it as argument remember to put in in quotes "".

Comment: '@echo off
move "path/test.bat" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop"
pause'

Comment: Output: 'The System Cannot Find The Path Specified."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the "":

```
move "A:\test.bat" "C:\Some folder"
```

Comment: "Cannot find the drive specified."
test.bat is in the same folder as this batch folder.

Comment: i think the point that fedxc is making is that your paths with spaces need to be surrounded in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permissions issue for the path you're trying.  Try opening the command line as an administrator (right click -> run as administrator)

This works fine for me when the batch file is run from the directory that the test file is in:

move "test.txt" "C:\Test"

Answer (score 0):

You must use backslashes `\` as path separators. According to your comment you used forward slash `/` in source path.

Comment: This is wrong. Batch files (.bat) are Windows, which uses backslashes as the path separator. (Recent Windows versions will, in most cases, accept either one.)

Comment: Sorry I have confused them. I corrected the answer, as it should stand for.

Comment: And the comment I have referred is "'@echo off move "path/test.bat" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop" pause'".

Comment: It's still a wrong answer; just not for the same reason. See the note in my previous comment about recent Windows versions. The `/` and '\' in the reference you used aren't enough to make it fail.

Comment: I tried it on my desktop. I got the same error while using `/` and when i corrected it to `\` it worked.

Comment: That's my point. `/` didn't work, because it didn't need a path separator. Correcting it to `` worked. We can do this all night, and it won't change anything. The answer you posted isn't the correct answer for this question, I'm afraid. :)

Comment: I wrote it in comment first. Check out John's responses.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a file or a folder relative to the location of the batch script you need to use the `%0` parameter and the `~dp` combined modifier. The following moves the file `somefile.txt` to `Some folder` on `C:`:

```
MOVE "%~dp0somefile.txt" "C:\Some folder"
```